# What does this quote from "The Fault in Our Stars" mean?

Tags: meaning

The following quote is from the book *The Fault in Our Stars*, by John Green:

> Whenever you read a cancer booklet or website or whatever, they always list depression among the side effects of cancer. But, in fact, depression is not a side effect of cancer. Depression is a side effect of dying. (Cancer is also a side effect of dying. Almost everything is, really.)  (Additional context: [Excerpt](http://books.usatoday.com/bookbuzz/post/2011-11-01/john-green-excerpt/560409/1))

What does this quote mean?

Comment: Does anything in the question affect you personally? If so, other contributors may know of somewhere you can receive help. But as it is not strictly a question about the English language you may find that it gets closed.

Comment: @meaning: I have edited your question to include context and to help our audience understand that the entirety of your original question was a direct quote from the book. I have also added a link to the surrounding paragraphs. Please let us know if I have inferred too much with this edit, but I think this will prove helpful to understanding your need.

Comment: The quote is in plain English. Please explain what part of it you have trouble understanding. If relevant, please include which dictionary you have consulted.

Comment: It sounds clever but is utter nonsense first to last. First off, the term *side effect* applies to medications and therapies, not diseases. Second, one can say that since we are mortals our lives tend inevitably towards death; but on that account to collapse the distinction between the antonyms *living* and *dying* is just silly.

Comment: If you follow the link (thanks, @Nonnal), you'll find that the quote belongs to a character in a novel.  The character is a 17-year-old girl with cancer.  She's an ironic and semi-detached observer of her own life.  It probably won't help you understand the novel to take her words too literally or expect them to be totally rational.